# Splash + HAProxy + Docker Compose (aquarium) -running but cannot see in browser

Tags: docker-compose, scrapy-splash

After running docker -compose up. all my splash instances started . It shows site starting at 8050 . but when i use my ip:8050 in my browser splash page is not obtained (site cannot be reached). is there anything i have done wrong?

```
splash2_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.186059 [-] verbosity=1, slots=5, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=3600.0
splash3_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:55.871821 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
splash2_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.187635 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
splash3_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.189226 [-] verbosity=1, slots=5, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=3600.0
splash2_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.193500 [-] Site starting on 8050
splash3_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.192182 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
splash2_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.196455 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f4739fb4a20>
splash3_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.196119 [-] Site starting on 8050
splash3_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.205247 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f453f3cfa20>
splash0_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:55.933366 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
splash0_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.233665 [-] verbosity=1, slots=5, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=3600.0
splash0_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.234555 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
splash0_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.237084 [-] Site starting on 8050
splash0_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.239519 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f402f0bda58>
splash4_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:55.965629 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
splash4_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.255030 [-] verbosity=1, slots=5, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=3600.0
splash4_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.255929 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
splash4_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.258017 [-] Site starting on 8050
splash4_1  | 2019-08-18 06:45:57.258832 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f60ece0aa20>
```

[the haproxy shows exit 1 state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5iFf.png)

[The error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OghNo.png)

Answer (score 1):

From your printscreen you can see that the proxy failed to start so that is already a problem.

More important, the other containers show that they expose port 8050 but that is not mapped to your host. For that reason you cannot access anything on that port.

After you fix the proxy (maybe it didn't start because a port conflict?) then you will see with `docker-compose ps` that it maps a port on host. You will be able to open `http://localhost:<proxy_host_port>` in your browser.

Comment: How do i fix that? i have uploaded the pic of the error im getting.

Comment: The error mentions a syntax error. Can you post your docker-compose.yml and any Dockerfile you might have?